# how to get image in pictuerBox from url in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

i have one url of image and i want to show that image in my `pictureBox` in winforms. this picture should be displayed on load of form `frmDash`. but i am not able to do it. I have used `Server.MapPath` but its not working. i googled about this and i came to know that i cant use Server.mapPath in winforms. dont know why. i have tried this:

```
public partial class frmDash : Form
    {

        string eId = string.Empty;
        string accept_notif;
        string Emp_Name;
        string store_Name;
        string Emp_Img;

 public frmDash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            eId = GlolbalUtil.loginEid;
            accept_notif = GlolbalUtil.accept_status;
            Emp_Name = GlolbalUtil.Emp_Name;
            store_Name = GlolbalUtil.store_Name;

            string remoteImageUrl = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUixBnM6uZD6Rlq3rut-jfK45mMAQdefbzUzFtXONkVxxCAxon";
            string strRealname = Path.GetFileName(remoteImageUrl);
            string exts = Path.GetExtension(remoteImageUrl);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(remoteImageUrl, Server.MapPath("~/images/") + strRealname + exts);

            Emp_Img = ""; // ??? 

        }      




private void frmDash_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblName.Text = Emp_Name;
            lblStoreName.Text = store_Name;
           // pictureBox2 = Emp_Img;
        }
```

i dont know how to code further. how to get that picture in `pictureBox` and first download it. error at `Server` : name Server does not exist in current context

Comment: This is what you need `PictureBox.Load Method (String)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ..

You can just use pictureBox.ImageLocation = "your URL";

Comment: `pictureBox2.Image=GetImageFromUrl("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUixBnM6uZD6Rlq3rut-jfK45mMAQdefbzUzFtXONkVxxCAxon"); ` , but have u tried my solution?